# Spawn zones: the tile or the zone?

Tags: zombicide

One quick clarification.

I was playing with a new group of friends and the way they spawn the zombies is on the spawn tile (the red tile). Because of that, when the activation phase for the zombies comes, this group does the first walk from the tile to the zone where the tile is located.

How I play is, the red spawn tile marks the zone the zombies spawn; then, during activation, they will move to the next zone and not into the zone from the tile as the group above.

What's the correct way to spawn and do the movement for the zombie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tile (or possibly multiple tiles) is used to mark the zones that zombies spawn in, but the tile itself isn't a zone. Zombies can't be "in" the tile, they are in the zone that tile is on.

Comment: That's how I thought it worked.